# Apple Search Ads + Localytics

Tags: ios, localytics, apple-search-ads

How do you report Apple Search Ads attribution data to Localytics? I don't believe they are an integration partner. I can easily get the information myself by calling `requestAttributionDetailsWithBlock` on app launch but then how do I properly report that data to Localytics?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would set a custom dimension (https://docs.localytics.com/dev/ios.html#custom-dimensions-ios) for users who downloaded the app from ASO.. this would allow the dashboard users to split and filter all reports by this attribution source. You could also tag a custom event (https://docs.localytics.com/dev/ios.html#events-ios) for "Launched from Apple Search Ad" that approach is more limiting when looking at the user behavior downstream but might be easier to implement. Curious to hear how it goes!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm curious if you know if Localytics plans to support Apple Search Ads as an official ad platform with tracking like other platforms? Considering it is the native app store platform I would think it should be pretty high priority no?